NodeJS memory leak with Axios and Firebase
I'm running a NodeJS app and found out it is crashing from time to time due to a memory leak:

[108:0x6325ed0] 343424015 ms: Mark-Compact 251.8 (258.5) -> 251.1
(258.9) MB, 707.66 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.225, current mu = 0.008)
allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed

I've used Clinic.js and got the following profile from a 1 minute test with 2k requests:

The code is only doing Axios requests and getting data from Firebase.
Not sure how to continue exploring. Any hints will be appreciated.
Thanks
